# What is required for realtime messaging system?

Tags: web, chat, message

I want to create a realtime messaging system in Web. Which programming languages and styling languages are required for this project?
Thanks for your answers, have a nice day..

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need

1. Html
2. Javascript
3. CSS

Comment: How can Javascript refresh the website for new messages?

Comment: Html can do that